# saving a variable column name in text via python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

```
col = ['rss','intercept'] + ['coef_x_%d'%i for i in range(1,16)]
ind = ['model_pow_%d'%i for i in range(1,16)]
coef_matrix_simple = pd.DataFrame(index=ind, columns=col)

for i in range(1,16):
   coef_matrix_simple.iloc[i-1,0:i+2] = linear_regression(df, power=i, models_to_plot=models_to_plot)

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2g}'.format
coef_matrix_simple

np.savetxt('output.csv', coef_matrix_simple,  delimiter =" ")
```

I want to save the coef_matrix_simple along with ***col*** values as column name and ***ind*** values in the csv file. saving the ***coef_matrix_simple*** gives only numbers without any column name.

Comment: Please provide reproducible code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with pandas' `DataFrame.to_csv()` method. The usage in your case would be

```
coef_matrix_simple.to_csv("output.csv", sep=" ")
```

More information here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html